# Comparison of byte value and hexadecimal

Tags: java, hex, byte

I ran into a problem when comparing the value of a byte.
Theoretically, the following code snippet should return `true`, yet it returns `false`.

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    byte a = 3;
    if (MpegUtil.isSlice(a) == true) {
        System.out.print("Yes");
    }
    else System.out.print("No");
}

public static boolean isSlice(byte ID) {
    if (ID >= 1 && ID <= (byte) 0xaf) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

What the function `isSlice` does is: receive a byte and if it is between 1 and af (hex), it will return true, if it doesn't the returned value is False. Yet somehow it fails my test by answering `false` to 3.

Does anyone has an idea of why this function doesn't work?

EDIT:
Thank-you for the suggestion of removing the 'byte' cast, it does indeed allow the code to function, however once the compared value is superior or equal to '0x80' the result change back to being a wrong 'false'. I know this is caused by the fact that Java considers the byte to be signed (now i'm really looking forward to Java 8), but would there be any "cleaner" version than changing the condition to:

```
if (ID != 0 && ID >= (byte) 0xaf && ID <= (byte) 0x7f) return true
```

Since this condition doesn't seem at first glance logical, is there any more obvious way to fix this?

Comment: 0xAF is 175 in decimal. The maximum positive value of a byte in Java is 127 so you may have to rethink whatever it is you are doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because `(byte) 0xAF` is not what you think. Try printing the following, so you get the idea:

```
    System.out.println(0xaf); // 175
    System.out.println((byte) 0xaf); // -81
```

**Why is `(byte) 0xAF` negative?**

Print this:

```
System.out.println(Byte.MAX_VALUE); // 127
```

The range of a byte is `[-128, 127]` (256 numbers), so if you cast `175` to `byte`, you will get:

```
175 - 256 = -81
```

You can also try this:

```
System.out.println((byte) 128); // -128
System.out.println((byte) -129); // 127
System.out.println((byte) 256); // 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Bytes are signed in Java.  Coercing `0xaf` to byte produces a negative number.  The Java way is to do `int` comparisons.  Just remove the byte cast and all should start working.

Similarly if you need to compare 32-bit unsigned quantities, you are more-or-less forced to use `long` comparisons.

Lack of unsigned types is one of Java's more annoying (un)features.